# Get lag value from the last row where value from other column = 'n'

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is as follows

[image]

when flag = 'y' I want **col1** to be updated with the last flag = 'n' row.
I want the **col1** values in row num 5 & 6 to be updated with the last row where flag = n, i.e row 4
& similarly row 10,11 should be updated with row 9.

the data is sored by date in ascending order.
I was able to use

I was able to use lag function where only row num 5 gets updated with row num 4 value, but row 6 takes row 5 value which is incorrect.

```
SELECT ID, col1, flag, date, 
CASE WHEN flag = 'y' THEN LAG(col1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) 
     WHEN flag = 'n' THEN col1 END as col1_new
FROM my_table;
```

Could you please help me solve this so that - col1 takes the value of the last row where flag = 'n' dynamically.. ?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Provide sample data not as a picture but as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO code-formatted text.

Comment: Please don't litter your request with DBMS tags. Only tag the request with the one DBMS you are sing. I've removed the inappropriate tags. Add back the one you need.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thank you. I've updated the tags to SSMS (Microsoft SQL server management studio)

Comment: SSMS is client software, not DBMS.

Comment: Hi @Akina, please apologize my primitive knowledge about the acronyms. I'm using SSMS, unsure what DBMS it is. How do I check?

Comment: Execute `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: @Akina So you know SSMS is not DBMS, but you cannot hazard a guess of what dbms/language op is trying to get help for? Or did you just not feel compelled to include this assumption in your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LAG` does not suffice for this task. You need `LAST VALUE` with a condition and `IGNORE NULLS` for this:

```
SELECT 
  ID, col1, flag, date, 
  CASE WHEN flag = 'y' THEN 
    LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN flag = 'n' THEN col1 END IGNORE NULLS)
      OVER (PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY date
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  ELSE
    col1
  END AS col1_new
FROM my_table
ORDER BY id, date;
```

This can even be simplified to

```
SELECT 
  ID, col1, flag, date, 
  LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN flag = 'n' THEN col1 END IGNORE NULLS)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS col1_new
FROM my_table
ORDER BY id, date;
```

because for an 'n' row the value to show is the last 'n' row value, too, if we include this row in the window.

### UPDATE

As SQL Server lacks the `IGNORE NULLS` clause (which renders `LAST_VALUE` useless here and probably also in almost every other scenario), I see two options to solve this with SQL in SQL Server.

**Use a subquery**

```
SELECT 
  ID, col1, flag, date, 
  CASE WHEN flag = 'y' THEN 
  (  
    SELECT TOP(1) col1
    FROM my_table t2
    WHERE t2.id = t.id AND t2.date <= t.date AND t2.flag = 'n'
    ORDER BY date DESC, col1 DESC
  )
  ELSE
    col1
  END AS col1_new
FROM my_table t
ORDER BY id, date, flag, col1;
```

**Iterate through the table with a recursive query**

```
WITH numbered AS
(
  SELECT
    t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date, flag, col1) as rn
  FROM my_table t
)
, cte (id, col1, flag, date, rn, last_n_col1) AS
(
  SELECT
    id, col1, flag, date, rn,
    CASE WHEN flag = 'n' THEN col1 ELSE NULL END
  FROM numbered
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    n.id, n.col1, n.flag, n.date, n.rn,
    CASE WHEN n.flag = 'n' THEN n.col1 ELSE cte.last_n_col1 END
  FROM cte
  JOIN numbered n ON n.id = cte.id and n.rn = cte.rn + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, rn;
```

Comment: Hi @thorten, thank you for you reply. I tried the code, it says incorrect syntax new 'IGNORE'

Comment: Ah, too bad. I've just looked up the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. At first it seems this should work, but scrolling down we see `"[ IGNORE NULLS | RESPECT NULLS ] Applies to: Azure SQL Edge"`. So, it seems that SQL Server dos not feature this clause, yet.

Comment: As SQL Server does not comply with the SQL standard here, yet, `LAST_VALUE` is of no use for you. I see two options in SQL: 1. use a subquery to select the last 'n' row value, 2. iterate through the table by reading it in a recursive query.

Comment: Thanks for checking it @thorsten, I was looking at the error too and it pointed me to the same link you've provided.

Comment: Could you please update script with your answer? I'm not quite sure on using either of the options you've provided.... Thank you for your help !

Comment: I've updated my answer. Did you even try to write one of the queries? The subquery solution is not that difficult and was the typical way to approach such problems, before window functions (`LAG`, `LAST_VALUE`, etc.) became popular.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten! I was only focusing on LAG and was thinking what could be a solution there. Havent tried either of your ways. But now I've learnt! Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @thorsten, the subquery didn't yield the correct results as well. I've validated both col1 and col1_new from the results. they both are the same. There was no row where the data differed. Trying the second solution gave me an error which is "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion"

Comment: My date column has duplicate dates and NULL values, so I've used <= to satisfy same dates if it occurs. t2.date <= t.date. But that didn't give me the correct results too.

Comment: It works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a37831cac280ee875034ec6d1942e15f. As to " The maximum recursion" you can add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to remove the limit.

Comment: Duplicate dates? Then you need another column for the ties. Does the column row_num exist in your table or have you just shown it just for displaying purpose?

Comment: NULL dates? Where do you want to see those in the result list? Before all other dates or after?

Comment: row_num doesnt exist, I've created for displaying purpose

Comment: Sorry, by null dates I mean null dates in col1. I don't think it would matter though. Just the duplicate dates

Comment: Ah, so an 'n' row may contain col1 NULL, in which case you would want to show NULL in the following 'y' rows. This should not be a problem with the two new queries I posted (it would be for the `LAST_VALUE` query, though).

Comment: As to duplicate dates: Then with four rows for 2021-10-15, two with flag 'y' and two with flag 'n' - how do you tell their order? The result will look very different depending on the order in which you put these rows.

Comment: For duplicate dates in date column, col1 should take the last 'n' value, where the 'y' date is less than or equal to 'n' date row

Comment: Okay, so you want the two 'n' rows to come before the two 'y' rows. Thus the 'y' rows get the value of the preceding 'n' row. But which of the two? With two 'n' rows on the same date, which is first, which is last? Which of the two rows wins and has its col1 value taken to the 'y' rows?

Comment: In such a scenario, any of the two 'n' rows can win. Take the value from either, doesnt matter.

Comment: Okay, as mentioned, in order to deal with ties, find an order that is no longer ambiguous. Please try to apply this yourself. I don't have the time right now. I will update my answer later.

Comment: Your logic in the first query makes clear sense. I'm looking at rows where the flag is n followed by y. and the date is not duplicate too. n date is less than y date. Clearly y should have been updated with n values. Not sure why that ain't happening.

Comment: Okay, thanks for you help Thorsten. I've learn a lot from you today. Cheers!

Comment: I've updated the queries with sort keys that should work for the date ties. After all the order is date (as before), then flag ('n' before 'y'), then col1 (to get an unambiguous order in case of two rows with the same date and flag).

Comment: Thank you @Thorsten. The query worked :)

Answer (score 0):

**If the `col1` column is *strictly* monotonically increasing for the `n` rows,** we can simulate `LAST_VALUE` `IGNORE NULLS` using a windowed conditional `MAX`

```sql
SELECT 
  ID, col1, flag, date, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 'n' THEN col1 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS col1_new
FROM my_table
ORDER BY id, date;
```